# $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subset B \implies C \subset A \subseteq B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subset B$, can we say $C \subset A \subseteq B$?

I am working on a proof for topology, in which I have come across a scenario where I have something similar to that which is given above and would just like to know if I may use the implication from above?

Comment: NO. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You cannot use the implication because it is not true. $C\subset A$ does not follow from $A\subseteq B$ and $C\subset B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. An example: $A=\emptyset,\quad C=\{1\},\quad B=\{1,2\}$.